# Photoshop: HSL Color picker plugin?

Tags: images, plugins, adobe-photoshop, colors, processing

Is there a plugin that can let Photoshop use a [HSL color picker](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV), rather than HSV (which Adobe calls HSB)?

In other words, any/all of the following locations could have an HSL option:

[image]

Or perhaps a plugin with it's own color picker.

### Reference

```
     RGB             HSL         HSV (aka HSB)
=============  ===============  ================
(1,   0, 0  )  (  0°, 1, 0.5 )  (  0°, 1,   1  )   
(0.5, 1, 0.5)  (120°, 1, 0.75)  (120°, 0.5, 1  )   
(0,   0, 0.5)  (240°, 1, 0.25)  (240°, 1,   0.5)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a plugin called **HSBHSL** provided by Adobe Photoshop itself. Hope that solve your problem.

> **HSBHSL**
>   The "HSL&HSB" plug-in allows
>   conversion between RGB and HSL (Hue,
>   Saturation, and Lightness) and between
>   RGB and HSB (Hue, Saturation, and
>   Brightness) within Photoshop. This
>   plug-in also allows you to change the
>   Hue, Saturation, or Luminosity of an
>   image as independent channels. Or, to
>   change HSL/HSB using channel
>   operations (calculations).

Download here: [Adobe Photoshop Optional Plugins](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4688)

Comment: The package of plugins you linked doesn't seem to actually contain the HSBHSL plugin; even though the web-site says it does. But i can't really blame you for Adobe's lies. Accepted.

Comment: This should not be the accepted answer.  This plugin only allows you to view the HSL channel in the Channels panel, and doesn't alter any of the color pickers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a Photoshop plugin, but I solve this problem by using [HSL Color Picker](http://hslpicker.com/), a web app with an easy-to-remember URL:

[image: HSL Color Picker screenshot]

To transfer colors to and from Photoshop, copy and paste the web color value, since it gives the color information in a single value. (That's the #3faad4 value in the screenshot in the question.)

I, too, wish Photoshop had this feature. One can convert between HSB and HSL, but sometimes you really need HSL, as when dealing with [CSS3 colors](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/), which support [HSL](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/HSL) and [RGB](https://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS3/Color/RGB), but not HSB.